# Good methods for loading looped queries

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How can I run a file (mysql query loop) without the need to load a page. Is the only way by using a cronjob or is there any alternative solution.
Solutions I tried so far:
1) Keeping the php file open and auto reload it every 10 minutes.
2) Using an ajax to load the page while the user is on the page.
The problem is; The query is looped, it requires time to complete. How can this be established without the need to persist on reloading the page.
Codes:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600" >
<?php
    include("./includes/connect.php");
    $i = 1;
    $numberOfRows = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM table_name');
    $scoreboardquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY points DESC");
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($scoreboardquery)) || $i<=$numberOfRows){
        $scoreid = $row['id'];
        $mysql_qeury = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET scoreboard_rank = '$i' WHERE id = '$scoreid'");
    $i++;
    }
            if($mysql_qeury){
            echo "Done!";
        }else
            echo "Not Done";
?>
```

To give a clear idea about what I am trying to do. I am trying to give users a rank (1st, 2nd, 3rd) based on descending order of their points.
So on the fly, if there any solution to implement what I am trying to do, better, please come forward.

Comment: Try to create a stored procedure for table updating process, it will remove the load of looping from the application and will be much faster.

Comment: While developing the system, I ran 3 performance tests, and noticed that updating should surely stay away from the main file.

Comment: Is there no triggering factor by which points are awarded to users. From the query and the while loop it looks like it is trying to increment the field scoreboard_rank with 1 without any condition. Cant you try a single update query to do an increment of this field rather than looping?

Comment: The loop adds the incremented values to the results of the "ORDER BY points DESC" query. Is there a method to increment that without loop?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that detail. But there should be some code where you are executing update points where user = '$this_user'. So my suggestion is to move the whole process of updating the points and successively updating the ranks to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

run it in the background, use exec to call it from the command line

something like

```
exec("nohup php file.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

add path to file if needed, and sometimes path to php is needed.